# Where is the emphasis in "as well as" sentences?

Tags: grammar

"You cannot distrust your intuition as well as you cannot trust your ego."

which part of the 2 the writer here wants to stress out the importance more to the reader? that you should be careful of your ego or you should listen to your intuition? as well as stresses the precedent or the following parts?

thx

Comment: Wow, what a lot of negatives! It's very confusing. Where is the quote from? "as well as" can be used for comparison, and also as "also". Maybe the latter makes more sense.

Comment: What do you mean by latter?

Comment: when you are talking about two things, you can refer to the first one as the **former** and the second one as the **latter**. In this case, I was suggestion that "also" or "in addition to" makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my interpretation of your sentence, “as well” is employed with the meaning “to the same extent”; i.e. both parts are rendered equivalent in this respect. Thus, no preference is made.

Comment: Are you sure that's still true, with all those negatives about?  "you can drink as much beer as you can water" implies equality. "you cannot drink as much beer as you can water" implies inequality.

Comment: @JavaLatte However, “you can drink as much beer as you cannot water” does imply equality. And their sentence is essentially: “You can trust x as well as you cannot trust y.” Does that make sense?

Comment: it makes about as much sense as "an apple is as big as an orange isn't".

Comment: @JavaLatte Well I presumed trust and distrust are both present in everything. You never fully trust or distrust something, right? The “trust scale” doesn't show an absolute value.